# How to convert a symbol to a string in kdb+?

Tags: kdb, k

For example, if I have a list of symbols i.e `` (`A.ABC;`B.DEF;`C.GHI) `` or `` (`A;`B;`C) ``, how could I convert each item in the list to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, useful answers! While I was trying to solve this on my own in parallel, I came across `($)` that appears to work as well.

```
q)example:(`A;`B;`C)
q)updatedExample:($)example;
q)updatedExample
enlist "A"
enlist "B"
enlist "C"
```

Comment: `$` is the k primitive underpinning q's `string` function. It's not advised to use k code, better off sticking with q code, aka the `string` function

Comment: Thanks for the advice @terrylynch, I'll keep that in mind and refrain.

Answer (score 2):

`string` will convert them. It's an [atomic](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/atomic/) function

```
q)string (`A.ABC;`B.DEF;`C.GHI)
"A.ABC"
"B.DEF"
"C.GHI"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keyword string to do this documented [here](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/string/)

```
q)lst:(`A;`B;`C)
// convert to list of strings
q)string lst
,"A"
,"B"
,"C"
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned, `string` is what you're after.  In your example if you're interested in separating the prefix and suffix separated by the `.` you can do

```
q)a:(`A.ABC;`B.DEF;`C.GHI)
q)` vs' a
A ABC
B DEF
C GHI
```

and if you want to convert these to strings you can just use `string` again on the above.

Answer (score 1):

```
q)string each (`A.ABC;`B.DEF;`C.GHI) 
"A.ABC"
"B.DEF"
"C.GHI"
```

Answer (score 1):

use String() function.

```
q)d
employeeID firstName             lastName
-----------------------------------------------------
1001       Employee 1 First Name Employee 1 Last Name
1002       Employee 2 First Name Employee 2 Last Name
q)update firstName:string(firstName) from `d
`d
q)d
employeeID firstName               lastName
-------------------------------------------------------
1001       "Employee 1 First Name" Employee 1 Last Name
1002       "Employee 2 First Name" Employee 2 Last Name
```